# React no longer updating in browser on save after compiler error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, jsx

I'm new to react and I've noticed that after I create my app with create-react-app it automatically updates when I save it in VSCode. Normal behavior. However, as soon as I get my first compiler error, (it has been different errors), when I fix the issue and re-save it the browser is no longer showing updates. From trial and error I've noticed the broswer not showing updates after that first compiler error. After I fix the issue, I have to refresh the page every time to see updates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.env` file in the base path of the project and include `FAST_REFRESH=false`.

This disables fast refreshing and returns to hot reloading.

If you don't want to add a `.env` file, you can add
`"start": "FAST_REFRESH=false react-scripts start"` to package.json.